# IE Enhanced Protected Mode and CoCreateInstance

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, com, activex

I have an ActiveX control (plugin) that is running inside IE10 with Enhanced Protected Mode turned on in Windows 8. (It registers with CATID_AppContainerCompatible as per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx)

I need my plugin to talk to an out-of-proc COM server, but when I call CoCreateInstance I get a "Class not registered" error. I presume this is because the plugin has no read access to the registry.

Is there a way to make this work?

---

Update-

It turns out my assumption was wrong about the "Class not registered" error.

I've added my solution as an answer. I don't know why this was breaking it, something to do with the AppContainer isolation level of EPM I guess. Another assumption :/

If anyone can shed some more light on what's going on here, that would be helpful.

Comment: Does it work when IE is non in protected mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it work, I simply had to place my plugin DLL in the Program Files folder, or, add ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES (read, read & execute) to its file permissions.  Then I can CoCreate a COM object and talk with my COM local server.

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of things you cannot do when enhanced protected mode is turned on, it is a pretty powerful sandbox.  Talking to an out-of-proc COM server is certainly high on that list.  Cross-process interop is a favorite tool applied by the virus hackers.  Not just because it makes getting rid of the virus so difficult, it can completely and trivially bypass sandboxing restrictions.  There is no protected mode left when you can run code in another process, it utterly defeats the feature.

There's no real path forward here as long as you depend on that server.